# Lengthening Pandas Dataframe by setting column headers as a row values and having a value column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a bit stuck with how to reshape my dataframe into a shape that offers me more flexibility.

My current dataframe is as follows.

```
Orginal_df = pd.DataFrame([['Action', 1, 5, 3], 
                   ['Comedy', 2, 4, 6],
                   ['Drama', 3, 2, 10], 
                   ['Crime', 1, 6, 6],
                   ['Documentary', 2, 9, 3]],
                  columns=['Genre', 'Bob', 'Sara', 'Peter'])
Movies.head()
```

The shape I want my dataframe to be in is as follows:

```
Wanted_df = pd.DataFrame([['Action', 'Bob', 1], 
                        ['Comedy', 'Bob', 2],
                        ['Drama', 'Bob', 3], 
                        ['Crime', 'Bob', 1],
                        ['Documentary', 'Bob', 2],
                        ['Action', 'Sara', 5], 
                        ['Comedy', 'Sara', 4],
                        ['Drama', 'Sara', 2], 
                        ['Crime', 'Sara', 6],
                        ['Documentary', 'Sara', 9],
                        ['Action', 'Peter', 3], 
                        ['Comedy', 'Peter', 6],
                        ['Drama', 'Peter', 10], 
                        ['Crime', 'Peter', 6],
                        ['Documentary', 'Peter', 3]],
                  columns=['Genre', 'Name', 'Count'])
Wanted_df.head()
```

Methods that I have tried are either concatenating with a loop.

```
df_movies_genre_frequency_test = df_movies_genre_frequency[['index']]
for user in users:
     df_movies_genre_frequency_test = pd.concat(df_movies_genre_frequency_test + [df_movies_genre_frequency[['index', user]]])

df_movies_genre_frequency_test.head(40)
```

And I've also tried with the [df.melt(...)](https://www.skytowner.com/explore/pandas_dataframe_melt_method)

Any help on how to solve this is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion `pandas.melt()` will do the job, while you set the *Genre* as `id_vars=['Genre']`:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Genre'], var_name='Name', value_name='Count')
```

##### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Action', 1, 5, 3], 
                   ['Comedy', 2, 4, 6],
                   ['Drama', 3, 2, 10], 
                   ['Crime', 1, 6, 6],
                   ['Documentary', 2, 9, 3]],
                  columns=['Genre', 'Bob', 'Sara', 'Peter'])
df.melt(id_vars=['Genre'], var_name='Name', value_name='Count')
```

###### Output

|  | Genre | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Action | Bob | 1 |
| 1 | Comedy | Bob | 2 |
| 2 | Drama | Bob | 3 |
| 3 | Crime | Bob | 1 |
| 4 | Documentary | Bob | 2 |
| 5 | Action | Sara | 5 |
| 6 | Comedy | Sara | 4 |
| 7 | Drama | Sara | 2 |
| 8 | Crime | Sara | 6 |
| 9 | Documentary | Sara | 9 |
| 10 | Action | Peter | 3 |
| 11 | Comedy | Peter | 6 |
| 12 | Drama | Peter | 10 |
| 13 | Crime | Peter | 6 |
| 14 | Documentary | Peter | 3 |